# Shapley Values: What is the permutation of a set?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, shapley-value, explainable-ai

Apologies if this is a very simple question--I am very new to Shapley values!

I am reading through an [article](https://hughchen.github.io/its_blog/index.html#masking_missing) on Shapley values written by some of the original authors of the [SHAP paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2017/file/8a20a8621978632d76c43dfd28b67767-Paper.pdf). While their exposition is generally very clear, the technical details in section 1.6 are somewhat confusing (see picture below)

In this section they are explaining how we can compute the shapley value ($\phi_i(f,x^f)$) for a model $f$, an instance $x^f$, and a feature index $i$. The first line is simply the definition of a shapley value in which $v(s)= \mathbb{E}_{D}[f(x^f)|do(x_{S\cup \{i\}}]$ and is straightforward.

**However I have no idea what the object** $P$ **even is and how we get from the first to the second line in the below proof**

The expression $S\subseteq P$ appears to mean a subset of permutations, i.e. if $N=\{1,2,3\}$ then $P=\{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{1, 3, 2\}, ..., \{3, 2, 1\}\}$ ($|P|=3!=6$) and thus $S$ could be e.g. $\{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{3, 2, 1\}\}$ which does not seem to typecheck in the equation. Would someone be able to help me understand the notation here? Thank you so much for your help!

---

[image]

Comment: This makes no sense, but you can see there's a general sloppiness with the uses of "$\in$" and "$\subseteq$" simply by comparing the first sum over $S$ with the penultimate sum over $S.$  Because I haven't the time to investigate the notation, whose definitions appear to be buried in multiple "Technical details" sections, I haven't any clear idea of what "$W(|S|,|N|)$" might be, but I would suggest looking closely at its definition and going on from there.

Comment: @whuber That is a good point about the notational sloppiness—perhaps this is just some strange typo then. Regarding $W(|S|,|N|)$, it is the weight for each term in the Shapley value sum  ($\frac{(|N|-|S|-1)!|S|!}{N!}$) which just ensures that 1) the Shapley value is a weighted sum of each difference and 2) the total weight for each size is $|S|$ is the same ($\frac{1}{|N|}$)